# split a string with the space bar

Tags: java, split, spaces

The follow are my java code

i want to enter: asd 123456 hellohello

output:

asd

123456

hellohello

However it come out error. anyone can help me?

package test;

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class test1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);
        String cs = sc.next();

        String[] output = cs.split("\\s+");
        System.out.println(output[0]);
        System.out.println(output[1]);
        System.out.println(output[2]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Replace `sc.next();` with `sc.nextLine();`

Comment: I have learn a new thing thank you

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of things that I have fixed with your code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class SplitStringWithSpace {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String cs = sc.nextLine();
        //close the open resource for memory efficiency
        sc.close();
        System.out.println(cs);

        String[] output = cs.split("\\s+");
        for (String retval : output) {
            System.out.println(retval);
        }
    }
}
```

- Use the enhanced for loop so you dont have to manually navigate the array.
- Close the resource after you have used it.

Comment: Thank you i sole the question:)

Answer (score 0):

`next()` only returns next token in the input not the entire line , your code will throw `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` as it stands bcoz `output` has length equal to 1.

you need `nextLine()` method to get the entire line.

Comment: Thank you i sole the question>~<

Answer (score 0):

Here `sc.next()` uses `spaces` delimiter. So given the input as `foo bar`, you get:

```
sc.next(); //`foo`
sc.next(); //`bar`
```

Either you may go for `sc.nextLint()` and use rest of the code as it is. If you have to continue with `sc.next()`, you may try this code snippet.

```
while(sc.hasNext()) { //run until user press enter key
  System.out.println(sc.next());
}
```